# Using select by attribute query?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, query, select-by-attribute

Using Arc Desktop 10.3.1 I have a datetime field that is in the format of MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS   Some of the records have a only a date and some have both a time and a date.  I want to strip off the time part using .split(" ")[0] but I am having difficulty figuring out how to craft the query to only select the records that have a time part.  I have tried:

```
select * from !DateTime!.split(" ")[1] > 0
```

The logic being I want to select all records from DateTime where the trailing time is greater than 0, then after they are selected I will run the field calculator to strip the time.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe you might have a casting issue.  I think what is being returned by !DateTIme!.split(" ")[1] is probably a string and your boolean is evaluating if the string is greater than 0.  Try casting the returned value as a quantative type.  float(!DateTime!.split(" ")[1]).  I'm not sure that this is the problem hence the comment as opposed to answer, but give it a shot.

Comment: Another thought...  This will probably fail for records that don't split at (" "), because the [1] index will be a null reference.  You could add a try/except in there.  This would add some processing time, but depending on the number of records you are querying could be negligible.

Comment: The first query of yours failed as well.  I am not super familiar with the try/except so let me do some research on it and give it a shot.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Datetime is not a string; it just looks like one. You said yourself, "I have a datetime field".

Comment: Can it be casted as a string? i.e. str(dateTime)

Comment: I tried as string,  I also tried as string comparing to null like string(!datetime!.split(" ")[1] IS NOT NULL but that did not work either.

Comment: Where are you doing this from?  Are you doing an actual "select by attributes" or are you coding this in the field calculator?

Comment: both actually, I started in select by attributes but figured that wouldnt work, so then I am started to do it in a field calc codebox.  The issue is i really want the selection, so the tool runs only on the subset of records.  There are 90,000 records with 100 added daily,  maybe 40 of those 100 need the time stripped.  The expression to actually strip the time is easy and the split function works just fine on the datetime field, ie !datetime!.split(" ")[0] will remove the time just fine and only take the date.  Its just getting it to only select the records with a time that I am stuck on.

Comment: You will probably have to add a new field called "Time_Only"  and field calculate it based on your successful splitting of the datetime object and then select by attributes on that field.

Comment: Not a bad idea, and pretty easily done, I have some extra fields already sitting around holding nothing anyway. It wouldnt be hard to split to the new field, select on fields not null, then run split again.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43771/discussion-between-geojohn-and-ed-hankins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a python solution for you.  This will create two layers, one with records with time, and one with records without time:

```
#feature class to be queried
fc = r'Path to your feature class'

#empty lists for the IDs
IDList = []
StripList = []

#search cursor to grab ID of records with Date and Time - change field names to match your fields
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,["Date","Unique_ID"]) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        Date = len(str(row[0]))
        ID = row[1]
        #records with time
        if Date>10:
            IDList.append("'{}'".format(row[1]))
        #records without time
        if Date<10:
            StripList.append("'{}'".format(row[1]))
del cur

IDs = ",".join(IDList)
#Query to select records with time
IDQuery = "Unique_ID In (" + IDs + ")"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc,"ID_lyr")
#layer with records with time - ID_lyr
ID_lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer("ID_lyr")
ID_lyr.definitionQuery = IDQuery
Strippers = ",".join(StripList)
#Query to select records without time
StripQuery = "Unique_ID In (" + Strippers + ")"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc,"Strip_lyr")
#layer with records without time - Strip_lyr
Strip_lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer("Strip_lyr")
Strip_lyr.definitionQuery = StripQuery
```